# Resharper is wraping my code when I CleanCode?

Tags: c#, resharper

I want to ask how to make override C# style in `ReSharper` clean code because I want to make my list declaration in one line instead of multi line per property
what I want

```
var listOfValues = new List<Value>
{
    new Value{ UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(),ControlId = 1,Name=""},
    new Value{ UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(),ControlId = 1,Name=""},
    new Value{ UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(),ControlId = 1,Name=""},
}
```

I don't want this style

```
var listOfValues = new List<Value>
{
    new Value
    {
        UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        ControlId = 1,
        Name = "",
        Description = "",
        ModifiedBy = "",
        ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = "",
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
    },
    {
        UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        ControlId = 1,
        Name = "",
        Description = "",
        ModifiedBy = "",
        ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = "",
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
    },
    {
        UniqeId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        ControlId = 1,
        Name = "",
        Description = "",
        ModifiedBy = "",
        ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = "",
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
    }
};
```

Comment: `Resharper Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Line Breaks and Wrapping` There is an item called `Wrap object and collection initializer`. There's no disable, but you could try `Simple Wrap` to see if that "helps", but I don't think there is a way to disable it because honestly, I can't imagine anyone ever wanting the former with more than just a couple of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change *Wrap array initializer* to *Simple Wrap*.

[image: Wrap array initializer]

Hope it helps.